# How can I display summary data with values for each month in a different column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot-table

I have one date condition like from 1 Aug 2014 to 28 Feb 2015.  Now I want to display a record for each month in a different different column, like Aug 2014, Sep 2014, Oct 2014, Feb 2015.  How can I display data for each month in a different column.

Comment: Use Pivot Table. There are many example available on SO, just help yourself.

Comment: but in sql 2008 how can i use pivot table

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon. Note that one way you can get help for SQL Server 2008 is by either tagging the question with the tag or by mentioning it in the question or (best) doing both.  Also, as general rule, you should include a small sample of the data you want to process (not covering all 7 months; maybe covering 2 months) and the sample output you'd want for that data.  It makes it easier to be sure we understand what you want.  Also, don't forget that tables have names — surprisingly often, people have anonymous tables in SO questions.

Comment: Pivot would help, can you please post your sample data?

Comment: state     jan2015         feb2015           mar2015         apl2015    may15   bihar                                                                                                              Goa                                                                                                          assam

Comment: i want data like this

Comment: i have use pivot but sql its giving error for pivot keyword

Comment: this error is display when i am using pivot.............Incorrect syntax near 'pivot'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.

Answer (score 0):

I think Soniya you can read this link; it will help you...

you can use `PIVOT` for your quesion.

like as:-

```
   PIVOT
(
 SUM(Amount)
 FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, 
 may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
)AS X
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

Comment: Generally, this sort of answer is termed a 'link-only' answer and they're not a particularly good idea on SO.  One reason is 'link rot'; URLs go AWOL after a while.  You should really summarize something of what the article suggests should be done.